# C system function returns sh: Invoke-Item command not found

Tags: c, windows, gcc

I want to run a powershell command from c (gcc) and I was told to use the `system()` function and I get that output. The exact same thing happens in a vacuum as well (nothing else in the program). I am using windows. What I want to do is use `Invoke-Item`. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean in a vacuum?  You run it from the prompt?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you're trying to do, and the environment you're trying to do it in?

Comment: Also note `cls` is completely non-portable. I would discourage calling it via a `system()` call from within C. This isn't to say you can't, you can, its use is a bit nebulous.

Comment: The title is about `cls` while the body is about `Invoke-Item`. Could you please ask a clear question with reproducible code (see [mcve] and [ask]) before this question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run PowerShell commands using `system()` function, you need to do something like this:

```
system("powershell -Command \"<your-command-here>\"");
```

AFAIK, the default shell on Windows is Command Prompt. PowerShell is another shell and you need to invoke it first to run commands in it.

Example (run `dir` command):

Using Command Prompt:

```
> PowerShell.exe -Command "dir"
```

Using Linux Terminal:

```
$ powershell -Command "dir"
```

So, the above command format should work for your case also i.e.:

```
system("PowerShell.exe -Command \"Invoke-Item ...\"");
```